# enabling property for trails through scripts doesn't work for me (ROBLOX STUDIO)

Tags: properties, roblox

So basically, I have a katana tool and when you click it does a slice. I made a trail for it so whenever it does the animation it makes a trail. I want to make it only have the trail when I slice, but when I try to do it, it doesn't seem to work.

```
local StarterPack = game:GetService("StarterPack")
local katana = StarterPack.Katana

local trail = script.Parent

script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
    trail.Enabled = true
    wait(0.9)
    trail.Enabled = false
end)
```

Image of properties (https://i.stack.imgur.com/im7Yn.png)

Video https://streamable.com/um29a5

In my script, I'm attempting to enable the trail when the function is activated, then turning it off after 0.9 seconds. **None of it works, the trail doesn't show at all**. There aren't any errors in the output either. If someone could please help me that would be appreciated. ***im a beginner at scripting so please be a bit more descriptive***

Comment: In the video, you can see that the enabled property is true when i'm slicing my sword, but it doesn't create a trail effect. I've tried turning on the enabled property on manually before testing and it works, but it is enabled while walking and moving normally instead of just when slicing (not what i want)